# find max count of nested though relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, group-by, eloquent, nested

This is my Polling system models  and relations

```
Poll
id --- title
    hasManyQuestions();
Question
id --- poll_id  --- title 
 hasManyOptions();
 belongstoPoll();

Option
id --- option_id --- title
 hasManyvotes();
 belongstoQuestion();

Vote
id --- user_id --- option---id
blongsToOption();
```

I want this query

And this is only return to me count for each options I need 
`sum(count(options.votes)) for each question`

something like `$question->count('votes')`

```
$data['poll'] = Poll::where('id' , $id)
            ->where('status' , 'on')
            ->with('user')
            ->with(['questions' => function($query){

                $query->with(['options' => function($newQuery){
                    $newQuery->withCount('votes');

                }]);

            }])

            ->first();
```

For this data

```
questions[id:1 ,poll_id:10 , title:defender players]
options[id:1 , question_id:1 , title:Ramos]
options[id:2 , question_id:1 , title:Pique]
options[id:3 , question_id:1 , title:Ferdinand]

questions[id:2 ,poll_id:10 , title:attacker players]
options[id:4 , question_id:2 , title:Messi ]
options[id:5 , question_id:2 , title:Ronaldo]
options[id:6 , question_id:2 , title:Zlatan]

Votes[id:1 ,option_id: 6 , user_id:103]; //option 6 blongs to question 1
Votes[id:2 ,option_id: 6 , user_id:13]; //option 6 blongs to question 1
Votes[id:3 ,option_id: 2 , user_id:19]; //option 2 blongs to question 2
Votes[id:4 ,option_id: 1 , user_id:103] //option 1 blongs to question 2
Votes[id:5 ,option_id: 3 , user_id:1300]; //option 3 blongs to question 2
Votes[id:6 ,option_id: 2 , user_id:1980]; //option 2 blongs to question 2
```

So I want the query to get

question with id 1 has 4 votes

question with id 2 has 2 votes

Answer (score 1):

brito
I use this query . Is a better one exist?

```
Poll::where('id' , $id)
        ->where('status' , 'on')
        ->with('user')
        ->with(['questions' => function($query){
            $query->with(['options' => function($newQuery){
                $newQuery->withCount('votes');
            }]);
        }])
        ->first();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can achieve that using Eloquent, but instead raw expression

```
DB::table('poll')
->select(DB::raw('count(*) as votes, poll.title'))
->join('question', 'poll.id', '=', 'question.poll_id')
->join('option', 'question.id', '=', 'option.question_id')
->where('poll.status', 'on')
->groupBy('poll.title')
->get();
```